# Passing values from Visualforce component to controller and back

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, visualforce-component

I've created a component and a controller to be used for inserting images in Visualforce email templates. Adding `<c:VFC_EmailTemplateImage developerName="logo" width="105" height="95"/>`to email template code would render the image on the template.

Controller:

```
public without sharing class EmailTemplateImageController
{
    public String documentDeveloperName {get; set;}
    public Integer documentWidth {get; set;}
    public Integer documentHeight {get; set;}
    public String imageURL  {get; set;}

    public EmailTemplateImageController()
    {
        this.imageURL = generateImageURL();
    }

    public String generateImageURL()
    {
        Document emailTemplateImage = [SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName, Url FROM Document WHERE DeveloperName = :documentDeveloperName].get(0);
        String imageURL = null;
        String baseURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost();
        List<String> parts = baseURL.split('\\.');
        String serverInstanceName = null;
        if (parts.size() >= 2)
        {
            serverInstanceName = parts.get(1);
            String organizationId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
            imageURL = 'https://c.' + serverInstanceName
                    + '.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=' + emailTemplateImage.Id
                    + '&oid=' + organizationId;
        }
        return imageURL;
    }
}
```

Component:

```
<apex:component id="VFC_EmailTemplateImage" controller="EmailTemplateImageController" access="global">
    <apex:attribute type="String" name="developerName" assignTo="{!documentDeveloperName}" description="DeveloperName of Document"/>
    <apex:attribute type="Integer" name="width" assignTo="{!documentWidth}" description="Image width"/>
    <apex:attribute type="Integer" name="height" assignTo="{!documentHeight}" description="Image height"/>
    <img src="{!imageURL}" width="{!documentWidth}" height="{!documentHeight}"/>
</apex:component>
```

The above code does not work because the constructor is called before calling the setter fot `documentDeveloperName`. That's why the SOQL query does not work. I've also tried to add the setter

```
public void setDocumentDeveloperName(String developerName)
{
    documentDeveloperName = developerName;
    this.imageURL = generateImageURL();
}
```

but it also does not work.

How to pass the `imageURL` value back to component after initializing `documentDeveloperName`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is addressed by understanding the order of execution for custom VF components

1. Constructor called
2. Setters called (from the component's `apex:attribute` `assignTo`
3. Getters called

As such, you should restructure your VF Component controller to:

```
public without sharing class EmailTemplateImageController
{
  public String documentDeveloperName {get; set;}  // set by component assignTo
  public Integer documentWidth {get; set;} // set by component assignTo
  public Integer documentHeight {get; set;} // set by component assignTo
  public String imageURL  {
    get {
       return generateImageUrl();
    }
    private set;
  }
 public EmailTemplateImageController() {} // let getter do work


public String generateImageURL()
 {
    Document emailTemplateImage = [SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName, Url 
         FROM Document 
         WHERE DeveloperName = :this.documentDeveloperName].get(0);
    String imageURL = null;
    String baseURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost();
    List<String> parts = baseURL.split('\\.');
    String serverInstanceName = null;
    if (parts.size() >= 2)
    {
        serverInstanceName = parts.get(1);
        String organizationId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
        imageURL = 'https://c.' + serverInstanceName
                + '.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=' + emailTemplateImage.Id
                + '&oid=' + organizationId;
    }
    return imageURL;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. What i did ,

create one tempVariable in vf apex class. Call whatever pre action you want to perform before constructor load . call that method from temvariable getter method and return empty string.

simply add the value in the page after page tag.

```
<apex:page>
{!tempVariable}<!-- Keep this var on top of all tag-->
  <c: component developerName = {!developerNameVar}
</apex:Page>
```

apex class would be

```
  public class test
 {
     public string developerNameVar{get;set;}
     public static stringtempVariable{ 
      get{
            developerNameVar = getDeveloperNameFromMethod();
         } 
       } 
     public string getDeveloperNameFromMethod()
    {
        // Do process
         return passingString
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, bharath. There is a problem that I cannot use another controller because I'm using component inside email template, not in Visualforce page

Comment: No, I'm passing it directly from Visualforce Email Template using <c:VFC_EmailTemplateImage developerName="logo" width="105" height="95"/> The email template does not have it's controller.

Comment: If you passing developerName='logo'. then it should work.

Comment: I'm not allowed to add {!tempVariable} just before calling component, I get error. But I can add it to the component adding {!tempVariable} just before apex:attribute tags. But then how to receive passingString in component's controller without autom atically calling the setter?